# Why does this code not only prevent the page from displaying, but also causes my computer to become unstable?

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net, code-conversion

I've got code in an ASP.NET WebForms app, in a Page_Load handler, that not only doesn't do what I want it to do (for now, show a bunch of checkboxes with a corresponding label that simply say "something") but also causes the page to not be displayed, and even causes the mouse to become unresponsive until I kill the instance of the browser, and opens up random windows to boot - Windows Explorer, then the Visual Studio Server Explorer (which I haven't opened in quite some time).

When I open the page with the event code commented out, the page displays, but even then (this may be a clue, I don't know) when I mash F12, the Console tab says, "The attached page targets document mode 7. Some console APIs and features may not be available." The same message appears at the top of the Debugger tab.

I don't know if that "document mode 7" stuff is harmless or just weird, or what, though.

Here is the code that seems to wreaking havoc; this is the contents of the entire .aspx.vb file:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports DAL05.DataAccess

Partial Class pages_custmaint_categoryadmin
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 'Handles Me.Load
        Dim sqlDAL As New SQLServer(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("ConnectionString"))
        Dim sql As String
        Dim retDS As DataSet
        Dim categoryDT As DataTable
        sql = "select C.CompanyName from CustomerCategoryLog CCL join Customers C on C.CustNo = CCL.Custno where CCL.Category = 'New' and C.Active <> 0 order by C.CompanyName"
        retDS = sqlDAL.runSQLDataSet(sql)
        categoryDT = retDS.Tables(0)
        'CategoryDDL.DataSource = categoryDT
        'CategoryDDL.DataTextField = "Category"
        'CategoryDDL.DataBind()

        For i As Integer = 0 To categoryDT.Rows.Count
            For j As Integer = 0 To categoryDT.Rows.Count
                Dim coName = New Label()
                coName.Text = "something" 'categoryDT.Rows[i].ToString()
                formCustCatMaint.Controls.Add(coName)
                Dim chk = New CheckBox()
                chk.ID = "chk." + i.ToString() + "." + j.ToString()
                formCustCatMaint.Controls.Add(chk)
            Next
            Dim l = New Label()
            l.Text = "<br>"
            formCustCatMaint.Controls.Add(l)
        Next

        sqlDAL.Dispose()

    End Sub
End Class
```

The corresponding .aspx page is simply this:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="custmaint_categoryadmin.aspx.vb" Inherits="pages_custmaint_categoryadmin" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Customer Category Maintenance</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="formCustCatMaint" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="675px">Move the following from &quot;New&quot; to &quot;Existing&quot; (uncheck any that should remain &quot;New&quot;)</asp:TextBox>

    </div>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="582px">
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Update checked to &quot;Existing&quot;" Width="216px" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

If all the code in the Page_Load event is commented out, there's no bizarre behavior (except for the "mode 7" message). What is it in the above code that could be causing such mayhem?

I got this basic code - to dynamically create checkboxes - from the accepted solution [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27183550/Create-an-Array-of-Checkboxes-or-create-dynamically.html) and ran it through Telerik's C# to VB.NET converter [here](http://converter.telerik.com/) and so have adapted it to my needs as seen above.

There are a lot of rows returned (thousands) from the query, but not enough to cause this kind of a problem, I wouldn't think.

### UPDATE

The event is being fired, because after commenting out all the other code, I added this to test it:

```
TextBox1.Text = "whatever"
```

...and it works - TextBox1's text is changed to "whatever"

So something is wrong with the query code. What, though?

### UPDATE 2

I am going to try to test this with baby steps; I reduced the code to this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim sqlDAL As New SQLServer(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("ConnectionString"))
    Dim sql As String
    Dim retDS As DataSet
    Dim categoryDT As DataTable
    sql = "select distinct CompanyName from Customers"
    retDS = sqlDAL.runSQLDataSet(sql)
    categoryDT = retDS.Tables(0)

    sqlDAL.Dispose()

End Sub
```

...and the page loads; of course, it shows no data, but I will continue adding to it to see where the breakdown occurs. Is the query too complex? Is the problem in the loop logic? Or what/where?

### UPDATE 3

Next, between the assignment to the DataTable and the sqlDAL.Dispose, I've added this:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 5 'categoryDT.Rows.Count
    For j As Integer = 0 To 3 'categoryDT.Rows.Count
        Dim coName = New Label()
        coName.Text = "something" 'categoryDT.Rows[i].ToString()
        formCustCatMaint.Controls.Add(coName)
        Dim chk = New CheckBox()
        chk.AutoPostBack = True
        chk.ID = "chk." + i.ToString() + "." + j.ToString()
        formCustCatMaint.Controls.Add(chk)
    Next
    Dim l = New Label()
    l.Text = "<br>"
    formCustCatMaint.Controls.Add(l)
Next
```

...which is as before, but with hard-coded small values rather than the DataTable row count as loop limits.

It sort of works, after a fashion:

[image]

An ugly fashion, admittedly, but it helps me to see that the problem must be with the categoryDT.Rows.Count...

So I reinstated the real query string, commented out the test one, and added this:

```
TextBox1.Text = categoryDT.Rows.Count.ToString()
```

...and see that the value is 26,821. Maybe that's the problem - too much data to deal with...that's a lot of checkboxes....

### UPDATE 4

The result set only has one column, as it only returns one value, so I was able to simplify the loop code to this:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To categoryDT.Rows.Count
    Dim coName = New Label()
    coName.Text = "something"
    formCustCatMaint.Controls.Add(coName)
    Dim chk = New CheckBox()
    chk.ID = "chk." + i.ToString() '+ "." + i.ToString()
    formCustCatMaint.Controls.Add(chk)
Next
```

Of course, "something" as the label for every checkbox doesn't quite cut the mustard; next challenge is to find out how to get the value from the result set/table. categoryDT.Rows[i] is not it; categoryDT.Rows[i] As String is not it...

### UPDATE 5

I tried this code to get the results from the table:

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To categoryDT.Rows.Count-1
        Dim coName = New Label()
        categoryDT.Rows(i).ToString()
        formCustCatMaint.Controls.Add(coName)
        Dim chk = New CheckBox()
        chk.ID = "chk." + i.ToString() '+ "." + i.ToString()
        formCustCatMaint.Controls.Add(chk)
    Next
```

...but I just get beaucoup checkboxes with the same label ("System.Data.DataRow").

Comment: Just a note about document mode 7, look at your doctype. It might be the browser may not support your code.

Comment: I don't know ow to look at doctype (I don't know what you mean by that). But the code is sort of working, now, so I don't think that's really a problem...

Comment: Are you new to Visual Studio? It looks like you're struggling at how to get at the text you want to use for the checkboxes. For starters, have you tried fofik's?: `coName.Text = categoryDT.Rows(i)(j).ToString()` Also, are you familiar with the QuickWatch feature of Visual Studio (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taedcee.aspx)? Put a breakpoint inside the loop, then use QuickWatch to poke around.

Comment: The normal debugging capabilities are not available to me with this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop you write rows twice. If you have 1000 rows this causes creating 1M controls. This can be the problem.

Below I changed second loop to iterate over columns.

Additionaly you may want to change coName.Text  as below.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To categoryDT.Rows.Count - 1
        For j As Integer = 0 To categoryDT.Columns.Count - 1
            Dim coName = New Label()
            coName.Text = categoryDT.Rows(i)(j).ToString()
            formCustCatMaint.Controls.Add(coName)
            Dim chk = New CheckBox()
            chk.ID = "chk." + i.ToString() + "." + j.ToString()
            formCustCatMaint.Controls.Add(chk)
        Next
        Dim l = New Label()
        l.Text = "<br>"
        formCustCatMaint.Controls.Add(l)
    Next
```

Comment: You seem to be just copying my code; what is the fixed code?

Comment: For j As Integer = 0 To categoryDT.Columns.Count

Comment: Please check coName.Text value also.

Comment: Any chance that: `For j As Integer = 0 To (categoryDT.Columns.Count - 1)`; similarly: `For i As Integer = 0 To (categoryDT.Rows.Count - 1)`? I.e. `for(int j=0; j<n; ++j)` ==> `For j As Integer = 0 To (n-1)`

Answer (score 0):

For the full solution, here is what the code needs to be, utilizing fofik's guidance, to get what I need on the page, and all checkboxes checked by default:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim sqlDAL As New SQLServer(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("ConnectionString"))
    Dim sql As String
    Dim retDS As DataSet
    Dim categoryDT As DataTable
    sql = "select C.CompanyName from CustomerCategoryLog CCL join Customers C on C.CustNo = CCL.Custno where CCL.Category = 'New' and C.Active <> 0 order by C.CompanyName"
    retDS = sqlDAL.runSQLDataSet(sql)
    categoryDT = retDS.Tables(0)

    For i As Integer = 0 To categoryDT.Rows.Count-1
        Dim coName = New Label()
        coName.Text = categoryDT.Rows(i)(0).ToString()
        formCustCatMaint.Controls.Add(coName)
        Dim chk = New CheckBox()
        chk.ID = "chk." + i.ToString()
        chk.Checked = True
        formCustCatMaint.Controls.Add(chk)
        ' Add a "line break" after each checkbox
        Dim l = New Label()
        l.Text = "<br>"
        formCustCatMaint.Controls.Add(l)
    Next

    sqlDAL.Dispose()
End Sub
```